# How to show a teaser of the next node?

Tags: nodes

At the bottom of each blog post I need to **show a teaser for the next blog post**. I know there is module to add links to next/prev blog. But I need to show more than a link. I need to show the title and summary. Could someone please suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: Assuming you want the next blog in date created order. That could easily be done with a little bit of custom code in a block. You could get the created date of the current node and then do an entityquery/database query to return 1 node of type blog with a created date greater than the current blogs created date and then sorted by created ASC

Answer (score 0):

I was able to achieve it by using the helper service defined in https://www.drupal.org/project/prev_next.